# What are sufficient prerequisites for the quotient induced by an order isomorphism to induce a well-order?

Tags: order-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, monoid, quotient-group

Let $X,\succ$ be a countable multiplicative abelian monoid with a partial order that is not a wellorder but is bounded below by $0$.

Let $Q\subsetneq X$ be a submonoid containing all its own multiplicative inverses.

Let $X\mapsto qX$ be an order isomorphism on $X$ for all $q\in Q$

This induces a monoidal quotient $X/Q$.

But does it induce some form of order-quotient ?

- $X,\succ/q$ for some $q\in Q$?
- $X,\succ/Q$?

> In particular, what are sufficient prerequisites for the $X,\succ/Q$ to be a wellorder?

**Example**

I see this as analogous to the conditions for a quotient of a group to be torsion.

I have the example of $Q$ being a dense everywhere subset (multiplicative subgroup) of $X$ and $X$ being a dense everywhere subset (mutliplicative monoid) of $\Bbb Q^+$.

$\succ$ order-embeds in $>$ the standard order on $\Bbb Q^+$.

In this case, Zorn's lemma holds in $X,\succ$ and I need to show that it holds in $X/Q,\succ$, and that $Q$ is the minimal element by all chains of $X/Q,\succ$ and that $X/Q,\succ$ is a wellorder.

Comment: Your second sentence does not make sense.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin let $X=\Bbb Q^+$ and let $Q=\langle2\rangle$ the multiplicative subgroup. $x\mapsto 2x$ is an order isomorphism, right? So I need to lower the case of $X$ to $x$, agreed?

Comment: A few issues to fix. (1) According to your first sentence, $X$ is a partially ordered set, but you never say that it is equipped with a product. (2) Apparently, you need a proper subset $Q$ of $X$. State it before using it. (3) Are you fixing some $q \in Q$ and then consider a map $x \to qx$? How do you know it is an order isomorphism? Are you assuming this property? (4) What is your definition of a quotient? For which structure?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin pin - I have added all you mentioned. The reason it was missing is that I was aiming to be as general as possible, rather than to introduce the conditions of my special case.  The vague part is the idea of an "order-quotient", i.e. when does the order induce a well-order in the quotient. In my special case $\succ$ is not $>$ although it does order-embed in it.  Then $\succ,\sim$ combine to make a well-order.

Comment: "The reason it was missing is that I was aiming to be as general as possible." Fine, but you still need to provide enough detail for the question to be readable without the reader having to guess what you mean. I also recommend putting some thought into the words you use and whether they are necessary or superfluous. For example, is there a difference between an "abelian monoid" and a "multiplicative abelian monoid". Is the word "multiplicative" playing a *necessary* role? (If so, then what?) Also if your monoid is abelian then there is no reason to specify that $Q$ is normal.

Comment: Anyway, given a set $X$, a partial order $<$ on $X$, an an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$, the most natural way to get a well-defined partial order on $X/{\sim}$ is to impose that $\sim$ is $<$-invariant, i.e., if $a<b$, $a\sim a'$, and $b\sim b'$, then $a'<b'$.

Comment: @halrankard re comment 1: I don't disagree with anything you've put.  I included "multiplicative" so $qX$ was meaningful which I later use.

Comment: @halrankard re 2nd comment: your "$\sim$ is $<$-invariant" is identical to my "every ray of the quotient map is an order-isomorphism", I believe, is that right?

Comment: Sorry, but a *normal submonoid* is an undefined notion, as a monoid does not have necessarily inverses.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin let a monoid $M=N\times G$ where $N$ is a monoid and $G$ is a group.  Then I define $M/G$ as a normal submonoid of $M$.  Does that work for you?  For example $\Bbb Z[\frac16]^+/\langle2,3\rangle$